# how to only copy files that will fit

Tags: linux, command-line, remote

I'm heading on a big trip tomorrow and want to copy some movies from a local drive to a usb stick.

The stick is 128GB and the drive has 183GB of movies.

I don't care which movies are copied and obviously I can't fit them all.  Is there a command line tool that will copy files until no more can fit?

Answer (score 1):

The command `cp` will do it.  It will continue copying files until the target device is full.
suppose your movies are in `/path/to/movies` and the  USB drive is mounted to `/mnt/usb`, the command will be:

```
cp -R /path/to/movies /mnt/usb
```